# Как изменить шаг значения слайдера кликом?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qslider

Нужно изменить шаг перемещения `QSlider` кликом.

Если зажимать ползунок слайдера и тащить в стороны, то значение слайдера будет изменяться с шагом **`1`**, 
а вот если кликать левее или правее ползунка, то шаг **`10`** пунктов.

Хочется, чтобы кликом левее или правее ползунка значение изменялось на **`1`**-**`2`** пункта, чтобы можно было выставить точное значение.

`setTickInterval(1)` и `setSingleStep(1)` - не помогают.

---

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLCDNumber, QSlider, 
    QVBoxLayout, QApplication)
from PyQt5 import QtGui


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def keyPressEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QKeyEvent):
        print('pressed')

    def initUI(self):
        lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
        lcd.display(40)
        sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        sld.setValue(40)

        sld.setTickInterval(1)
        sld.setRange(15,40)
        sld.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        sld.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBothSides)
        sld.setSingleStep(1)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(lcd)
        vbox.addWidget(sld)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        sld.valueChanged.connect(lcd.display)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Signal & slot')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> QSlider Class - Наследует: QAbstractSlider.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> pageStep : int
>
> Это свойство содержит шаг страницы.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLCDNumber, QSlider, QVBoxLayout, QApplication)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QKeyEvent

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Signal & slot')
        self.initUI()

    def keyPressEvent(self, a0: QKeyEvent):
        print('pressed')

    def initUI(self):
        self.lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
        self.lcd.display(40)
        sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        sld.setValue(40)
        
        sld.setPageStep(1)                     # <--- Это свойство содержит шаг страницы.

        sld.setTickInterval(5)                      
        sld.setRange(15, 40)
        sld.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        sld.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBothSides) 
        sld.setSingleStep(1)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.lcd)
        vbox.addWidget(sld)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        
        sld.valueChanged[int].connect(self.lcd.display)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]